# How to sequelize.js this SQL query

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I use sequelize on my nodeJS app to query a sql database.

I try to sequelize this query but it doesn't work...

Can one help me ?

```
`SELECT content, COUNT(*) count FROM `hashtags` GROUP BY content ORDER BY count DESC LIMIT 10`
```

I try

```
Tags.findAll({group: ['content'], attributes: ['content', [sequelize.fn('COUNT', 'content'), 'content']],}).then(function(results) {
```

Tags is a sequelize define with date, content, id_tweet, id.

I have another query but I don't have any idea to do this because there are 2 inner join and count:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS nombredetweets, h.content, u.pseudo FROM tweets t INNER JOIN hashtags h ON t.id = h.id_tweet INNER JOIN user u ON t.id_user = u.id WHERE h.content = ? AND u.pseudo = ?
```

Thanks ;)

Comment: Try X instead of count in case it's a reserved word issue?

Comment: How to do that ?

Comment: select content, count(*) X from `hashtags` group by content order by  X desc limit 10

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the problem is with how you name the count result. Try this:

```
Tags.findAll({
  group: ['content'],
  attributes: [
    'content',
    [
      sequelize.fn('COUNT', 'content'),
      'count'
    ]
  ],
  order: [['count', 'DESC']],
  limit: 10,
}).then(function(results) {
  // ...
})
```